# datagridview is complaining about 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.'

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
    private void importFile()
    {
        TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(@"E:\\test.csv");
        parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
        parser.SetDelimiters(",");
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "URL";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Valid";

        while (!parser.EndOfData)
        {
            //Processing row
            string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
            foreach (string field in fields)
            {
                //TODO: Process field
                // Crashes on line below with message
                // Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index
                DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Clone();                    


                row.Cells[0].Value = field;
                row.Cells[1].Value = "";
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
        parser.Close();
    }
```

Above is my code. It crashes on the line as noted above. I can't imagine why its crashing. Any assistance would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Does your `Datagridview1` has any row?

Comment: @SonerGönül see the 3 line comment in the code.

Comment: @Cocoa Dev how many times loop runs and it gets crashes? or in the first attempt only?

Comment: What is the value of dataGridView1.Rows.Count? (Before entering the loop)

Comment: I will be glad if he ask any of these comments.

Comment: Loop should fail on first iteartion as there are no rows when accessing dataGridView1.Rows[0]. This is not the right way to construct rows.

Comment: It crashes on 1st attempt.

Comment: @DavidGoshadze can you please tell me the correct way of constructing it? Thank you

Comment: dataGridView1.Rows.Add(fields); number of elements in fields must match number of datagrid columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line:

```
DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Clone();
```

Will fail the first time it is executed, because at this point you have no rows in dataGridView1, so index = 0 is out of range.

Try this in stead:

```
DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
```

You can read more here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.aspx

Comment: I am trying the same as you suggested but getting the same exception

Answer (score 1):

Being close to your code

```
    private void loadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string buffer = "1,2,3\r\n4,5,6\r\n7,8,9";
        TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(new MemoryStream(UTF8Encoding.Default.GetBytes(buffer)));
        parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
        parser.SetDelimiters(",");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

        while (!parser.EndOfData)
        {
            string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(fields);
        }
    }
```

My dagaGridView1 has 3 columns. I used MemoryStream instead of file parsing.

Comment: is that more efficient? My file has 45K entries and the UI freezes. I have to put the load into a background thread

Comment: I think it is, because iteration overhead is minimized. But background thread is good anyway, if you are dealing with large files.